# Inconsistent data with SlickGrid checkbox formatter/editor

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I was looking at the `SlickGrid`'s`editors`/`formatters` features to see how these would modify the `data` object used to build the grid (because as far as I understand, modifications made to the table are automatically replicated to the `data` object).

I was looking at a particular example which shows how `booleans` can be edited and formatted as checkboxes (instead of dealing with a `true` or `false` string) and noticed that the values replicated to the `data` object were inconsistent.

To see what I mean, edit the `effortDriven` column for the first 4 rows as follows:
-**Task 0**: don't touch
-**Task 1**: check
-**Task 2**: don't touch
-**Task 3**: check and uncheck

[image]

Now in your firebug console, alert the data object:

[image]

Here are the values you will get for the `effortDriven` field:
-**Task 0**: `true`
-**Task 1**: `checked`
-**Task 2**: `false`
-**Task 3**: `(void 0)`

As you can see, for a field that's initially supposed to be a `boolean`, we end up with 4 different values. As a general comment, I thought the logic with `formatters/editors` was only to check the visualization, but preserve integrity of the `data` object: **I would therefore strongly recommend people using `SlickGrid` to double-check how their `data` object is being updated when using `formatters/editors`, and don't assume data integrity is preserved**).

**How can I make sure my `data` object retains 2 `boolean` values while still using a checkbox on the UI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `CheckboxEditor` function in `slick.editors.js` as follows:

```
this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
  //item[args.column.field] = state;  <-- remove that line, add lines below
  if (state == 'checked') {
      item[args.column.field] = true;
  } else {
      item[args.column.field] = false;  
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem as well. In the custom `CheckboxEditor` in `slick.editors.js` just change the value serializer:

```
function CheckboxEditor(args) {

    ...

    this.serializeValue = function () {
        return $select.attr("checked") ? true : false;
    };

    ...

}
```